# Kibana specific permissions for AWS ElasticSearch domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

We've stumbled across an issue that is bothering us for some time and we would really appreciate your help.

Our problem lies with permissions for ElasticSearch service in combination with Kibana. We have ES domain with WRITE/READ permissions only from our Lambdas and READ permissions only from the IPs of our company offices. We use Kibana(on AWS, not local) for visualizing our data, and the problem is that we need to allow POST actions over the ES domains in order Kibana to be able to work, otherwise we just get permission issues. But that also means that we need to open POST requests for our company IPs, which is something we don’t want. Our question is how we can allow only Kibana to have that sort of permissions. Our goal is to have the READ/WRITE access only for our lambdas, READ permissions only for our company IPs and the needed permissions for Kibana in order to work without interfering with the rest of the permissions.

This is the access policy we have on the ES domain:

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "<ROLE_USED_BY_OUR_LAMBDA>"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "<ELASTICSEARCH_DOMAIN>/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "es:ESHttpGet",
        "es:ESHttpHead",
        "es:Describe*",
        "es:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": "<ELASTICSEARCH_DOMAIN>/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "<COMPANY_IP_1>",
            "<COMPANY_IP_2>",
            "<COMPANY_IP_3>"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you not put the kibana url behind a dedicated internal url and use it's ip address to have it in separate policy which allows access to POST as well? the rest of the ip addresses can only have read one

Comment: Hi Ashish, by dedicated internal url, do you mean to install on premise instance of Kibana in the company and use that one? Because right now we are using the pre-installed Kibana that comes with the elastic search service on the instance on AWS.

Comment: I meant put that aws generated kibana url behind some other URL. example myoffice.kibana.com -> aws.kibana.url.com

Comment: Hey Ashish, thanks for the comment. Just for clarification, in that case wouldn't the AWS Kibana eventually also contact the ES domain and still require the POST permissions? Or maybe if you have more concrete example of what you are trying to tell me, I would really be thankful :). Cheers.